# Installation of Ubuntu with windows 8

Tags: installation, usb, windows-8, uefi

I´m new on Linux and I have the Problem that i can`t install it on my PC.
The PC is original with Windows 8. I don't need the Windows I only want ubuntu on the PC but I am not able to install it.

I have made an live USB to start ubuntu but when I change the start up in BIOS that the PC should boot from USB I always get the Information that there is no way to start from USB I tried it on several ways an the secure start up is disabled, too.

Does anyone have an answer for me?

Thanks.

Comment: did you had an option on bios to boot from usb?

Comment: What program did you use to create the BOOT USB?

Answer (score 0):

Possible the stick is not written correctly, when I have used Windows 8, I have used [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) and always it worked.

Some systems boot automatically from hard disk on power on, and boot from others sources only on restart.

You try F12 button,and select the stick (this isn't for all systems)